# How to dynamically rename an appended item of a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to change a name dynamically on a html list, my rename functions works on the items that were already on the list, but doesn't work on the appended items 
My code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Append items functions
    $("#btn2").on('click', function () {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        $('<li>', {
            text: name
        }).appendTo('ol').append($('<button />', {
            'class': 'btn3',
             text: 'Remove'
        })).append($('<button />',{
            'class': 'btn4',
            text: 'Rename'
        }));
  });

  //delete items functions
  $(document).on('click', 'ol .btn3', function () {
      $(this).closest('li').remove();
  });

  //rename function 
  $(".btn4").on('click', function () {
      var rename = "test"//$('#rename').val();

  $(this).closest('li').after($('<li>', {
          text: rename
      }).appendTo('ol').append($('<button />', {
          'class': 'btn3',
          text: 'Remove'
      })).append($('<button />',{
         'class': 'btn4',
         text: 'Rename'
      }))).remove();
   });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class = "container">
 <ol>
   <li>List item 1 <button class="btn3">remove</button><button class="btn4">rename</button></li> 
   <li>List item 2 <button class="btn3">remove</button><button class="btn4">rename</button></li>
   <li>List item 3 <button class="btn3">remove</button><button class="btn4">rename</button></li>
 </ol>
</div>

<input id = "name" type = "text"> <button id="btn2">Append list items</button>

</body>
```

Tips and help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem area is this, your `.btn4` is also created dynamically so you need to use delegated event handlers.

```
 $(document).on('click', ".btn4", function () {
        var rename = "test" //$('#rename').val();

        $(this).closest('li').after($('<li>', {
            text: rename
        }).appendTo('ol').append($('<button />', {
            'class': 'btn3',
            text: 'Remove'
        })).append($('<button />', {
            'class': 'btn4',
            text: 'Rename'
        }))).remove();
    });
```

if `ol` is not generated dynamically in your original code them you can use

```
$('ol').on('click', ".btn4", function () { ... }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hKYgt/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is "Event delegation". In jQuery, that means to use

`$('window').on('click', 'li', function () { ... });`

Instead of

$('li').click(function () { ... });

This former is a single handler, applied to the window DOM object, listening for all clicks on li's within it. The latter is a separate click handler applied to each li *that is currently on the page*. The former will extend to all newcomers, the latter will not.

Hope this helps!